# How to use integers inside of an array as parameters for a method. (Tester)

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I calculate an integer and assign it into an array using a method inside a for loop, then the next method in that for loop needs the previous integer calculated as a parameter I declared it as an double which fixed that problem but **now I need to print the result and I  have the same problem, what do i put in the method parameters when printing because the variable was wiped after every loop in the first loop.**

This is the main method class :

```
public class AnnualFuelTester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //declaration of variables
        int endMiles, startMiles;
        double gallonsUsed, pricePerGallon;

        //initialization of an array of objects
        AnnualFuelUse[] fillUps = {
                new AnnualFuelUse(45023, 45231, 10.00, 2.95),
                new AnnualFuelUse(45231, 45480, 11.70, 2.99),
                new AnnualFuelUse(45480, 45659, 9.30, 3.03),
                new AnnualFuelUse(45659, 45961, 14.90, 3.05)
        };

        //call methods
        for (int index = 0; index < fillUps.length; index++) {
            double distance = fillUps[index].calcDistance();
            fillUps[index].calcMPG(distance);

            fillUps[index].getStartMiles();
            fillUps[index].getEndMiles();
            fillUps[index].getGallons();
            fillUps[index].totalCost(distance);
        }

        //print results
        System.out.printf(" %15s %15s %15s %15s %15s %15s %15s %15s %15s", "Fill Up", "Days", "Start Miles", "End Miles", "Distance", "Gallons", "Miles/Gal", "Gallons/Miles", "Price", "Total Cost\n");

        for (int index = 0; index < fillUps.length; index++) {
            System.out.printf("%15i %15i %15s %15s %15d %15d %15d %15d %15d", index, index, fillUps[index].getStartMiles(), fillUps[index].getEndMiles(), fillUps[index].calcDistance(), fillUps[index].getGallons(), fillUps[index].calcMPG(distance), fillUps[index].totalCost(distance), "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Class with the methods:

```
public class AnnualFuelUse {
    //private instance variables
    private int myEndMiles, myStartMiles;
    private double myGallonsUsed, myPricePerGallon;

    AnnualFuelUse(int sm, int em, double gu, double ppg) {

        myEndMiles = em;
        myStartMiles = sm;
        myGallonsUsed = gu;
        myPricePerGallon = ppg;
    }

    //distance driven
    public double calcDistance() {
        return myEndMiles - myStartMiles;
    }

    //calculate miles per gallon
    public double calcMPG(double distance) {
        return distance / myGallonsUsed;
    }

    //calculate gallons per mile
    public double calcGPM(double distance) {
        return (distance / myGallonsUsed) / 100;
    }

    //calculate total cost
    public double totalCost(double distance) {
        return myPricePerGallon * distance;
    }

    //getter start miles
    public int getStartMiles() {
        return myStartMiles;
    }

    //getter end miles
    public int getEndMiles() {
        return myEndMiles;
    }

    //getter gallons used
    public double getGallons() {
        return myGallonsUsed;
    }

    //getter price per gallon
    public double getPricePerGallon() {
        return myPricePerGallon;
    }
}
```

The instructions for this program are

1. If you have not yet created the 8.08 Annual Fuel Use project in the Mod08
   Assignments folder, please do so now.
2. Be sure to save a copy of these instructions in the Mod08 Documents folder.
3. Print a copy for your notebook.
4. Read the instructions carefully before you attempt the assignment.
5. Create two classes called
   AnnualFuelUseTester and AnnualFuelUse
   in the newly created project folder.
6. Use the fill up data you have been collecting
   for your car (or the family car) and calculate
   the total distance, gallons used, and cost of
   gas.
7. Determine the minimum and maximum
   values for distance, miles per gallon and
   price. (Recall the Integer class constancies
   MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE. The
   Double class also has class constants of the
   same name.)
8. Calculate annual projections for distance,
   gallons used, miles per gallon, and cost
   based on the data you collected.
9. Each fill up should be considered an object and your program design should be
   based on an array of objects. Use the demo program in this lesson as a model for
   how to create and process an array of objects.

Comment: Have your method `.calcDistance()` return a value (the one you require). store it in a variable or directly pass that to the second called function `.clacMPG()`

Comment: I need to use the variable more than once, and in more than one method. Would it still work? How would i do that? Thanks

Comment: Post all of your code and classes if you want help.

Comment: Yeah using a variable would do if you need to use it in the same loop.

Comment: I am doing this correctly, right? I need to calculate and print 4 fill ups to the screen using methods and objects and specifically i have to do it using an array. Can this be done just using the fillup array for every object? will that contain the variables like distance and cost and start miles and end miles, allowing me to print it at the end of the program? or do i need an array for each variable of each object?

Comment: you can basically use one variable which will get overwritten every time the loop runs. I also find few variables which are declared but not used in code. you can actually get rid of `int endMiles, startMiles;  
double gallonsUsed, pricePerGallon;`, instead declare `int dist` here and use it in the loop, this will have only one variable created in memory.

Comment: Vamshi I did what you said but i also need to use distance when I am printing the code. I'll update it now to show what I mean

Comment: why are you trying to print after the loop is executed? why not put the print statement also in the same loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100865/discussion-between-david-brewer-and-vamshi-krishna-alladi).

Answer (score 2):

If you are basically expecting the value calculated in `.calcDistance()` method, Have your method `.calcDistance()` return a value (the one you require).
Store it in a variable or directly pass that to the second called function `.clacMPG()`

As you are already returning a value from `.calcDistance()` you can do something like

`int dist = fillUps[index].calcDistance();`

and now you can use this `dist` value in any other method calls you make, like

`fillUps[index].calcMPG(dist);`

you can basically use one variable which will get overwritten every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable:

```
int dist=fillUps[index].calcDistance(); 
//or double, depands on the method's returning value

fillUps[index].calcMPG(dist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that AnnualFuelUse constructor arguments are: start miles (odometer), end miles, gallonsUsed and pricePerGallon.
One way to do this is returning the distance and passing as argument to the next:

```
    int distance = fillUps[index].calcDistance();
    fillUps[index].calcMPG(distance);
```

I can't see in your code how you are consolidating data and how you're projecting future data.

**Ok. Based on your "edit", now I know that you don't have a question, You want someone to do your homework for you!!! **